# passing extra variable to a callback

Tags: javascript, callback, asynccallback

I have the following call which runs a method within a cacheListener object asynchronously:

```
ohttp.asyncOpenCacheEntry(url, 4, cacheListener);
```

Here is what the callback object/function looks like:

```
var cacheListener = {
    onCacheEntryAvailable: function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    // do something.
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is add an extra argument to that callback. I've tried appending a third argument at the end of the call and then in the function definition, but it won't get passed properly like this (myArg at the end):

```
    ohttp.asyncOpenCacheEntry(url, 4, cacheListener, myArg);
```

Here is what the callback object/function looks like with the extra argument:

```
var cacheListener = {
    onCacheEntryAvailable: function(arg1, arg2, arg3, myArg) {
    // do something.
    }
}
```

myArg, as expectable, isn't passed, and I'm not sure how to make a construct that would allow for the argument to be passed properly.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: One thing I'm thinking about is putting all this code under the same object, and then create a "data" property that would be shared in all of these methods. This way I wouldn't have to pass anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to wrap it up if you don't control the code that's using your callback. Something like this:

```
ohttp.asyncOpenCacheEntry(url, 4, cacheListener, {
    onCacheEntryAvailable: function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
        cacheListener.onCacheEntryAvailable(arg1, arg2, arg3, myArg);
    }
});
```

If there are other methods in the callback objects then you'll have to wrap those too.